# Redirect all urls which contain certain parameters to another url which follows a certain pattern

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Unfortunately I didn't get it solved by myself and need to ask for help. I want to redirect all urls which follow a certain pattern (in this case it contains "reviews/category"). These URLs supposed to be redirect to another url which is made up the first one:

```
http://[product-url]/reviews/category/[category-url]
```

supposed to be redirect to

```
http://[product-url].html
```

Furthermore it shouldn't matter if you call the url with or without www.

Example:
http://example.com/ford-blues/reviews/category/cars supposed to be redirect to http://example.com/ford-blues.html

Any help would be much appreciated.

Following code isn't working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^reviews/category/?$ $1\.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/reviews/category/ /$1.html
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/reviews/category/ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/reviews/category/ $1.html (without the /) did the trick. It works!